# Jquery Scroll to #ID with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I´m trying to apply Scroll to a div after an ammount of time. This code works well, as it scrolls with delay, but I don´t know how to apply it to a specific DIV ID.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(function (){var scroll= $(window).scrollTop();
scroll= scroll+ 800; 
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: scroll}, 5000);}, 5000);
});
```

Comment: apply what to the div? scroll to the element? or scroll the element?

Comment: The page loads, and after some seconds y want to auto scroll to a section with an ID.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `offset()` method to get the `top` and `left` position of the element in the document.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    //get the offset of the target in the page
    var scroll = $('#target').offset().top;
    
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: scroll
    }, 2000);
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
#target {
  background-color: red;
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 1400px;
  margin-top: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, I think we almost got it but is still not doing what it sgould. It doesnt stop on the bottom section where the ID is. You can see it here. I think It stops on a point depending on the size of the screen. https://leyandlaw.callibree.com/